# How can I use .replaceWith to replace the source of an image?

Tags: jquery, html, css, replace

I have a image I'd like to replace but...

```
<div class="news-thumb-wrapper">
     <img src="/content/oldimage.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail" height="150" width="600">
     <div class="gallery-arrows"></div><h8><a href="/">Some text</a></h8></div>
```

I've used this code to try replace the entire img tag but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$( "img.attachment-post-thumbnail" ).replaceWith( "<img src="/content/newimage.png" class="attachment-post-thumbnail" height="41" width="600">" );
```

Could anyone please tell me what's wrong with the code?

Comment: For starters, that's not syntactically valid JS. Look at the syntax highlighting.

Comment: The quotes. You need to either escape your `"` inside your string. or use `'` instead.

Comment: @Ikillnukes - Don't correct code in questions. Supply an answer for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `replacewith` to replace the image. Just change the `src`:

```
$("selector for img").attr("src", "/content/newimage.jpg");
```

Comment: I don't see why mess with attributes, when the proper way would be manipulating the DOM properties. Okay, the `src` property is synchronized with the `src` attribute, but using `.attr()` unnecessarily is a bad example.

Comment: @Joe As I just said, this works because the `src` attribute and `src` property are reflected upon each other when one of them is changed. So, in this specific case, it doesn't matter. I'm just saying that `.prop()` is the correct way to do this. Which would you prefer? `img.setAttribute('src', 'url')` or `img.src = 'url'`? That's the difference between `.attr()` and `.prop()` - one is meant for HTML attributes and the other for DOM properties.

Comment: @TJ you have (IMO) the best answer at [.prop() vs .attr()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5884994/1331430), any reason to use `.attr()` in this case when you say `.prop()` should be technically preferred? Or just a preference choice here?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: *"I don't see why mess with attributes, when the proper way would be manipulating the DOM properties."* LOL I very nearly added a comment to the end of the answer saying this: *"Why I used `attr`: In case there were zero or multiple matching elements."* That's literally it, otherwise, I would have gone with `$("selector for the image")[0].src = "/content/newimage.jpg";` And yes, arguably `prop` would be the better way to go, but with `src`, it really doesn't matter.

Comment: Hahah makes sense. `:P` Accessing the DOM element is pretty faster than `.attr()`/`.prop()` so it'd be a good option if there is only one element.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has invalid syntax. You should escape the double quotes inside the string or use single quotes:

```
$( "img.attachment-post-thumbnail" ).replaceWith( '<img src="/content/newimage.png" class="attachment-post-thumbnail" height="41" width="600">' );
```

Now, the proper way to swap an image is to simply set its `src` property:

```
$( "img.attachment-post-thumbnail" ).prop('src', '/content/newimage.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

you use double cote inside double cote , what you should do is :

```
$( "img.attachment-post-thumbnail" ).replaceWith('<img src="/content/newimage.png" class="attachment-post-thumbnail" height="41" width="600">')
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try to **escape quotes** like that `"<img src=\"/content/newimage.png\" class=\"attachment-post-thumbnail\" height=\"41\" width=\"600\">"`

```
$( "img.attachment-post-thumbnail" ).replaceWith( "<img src=\"/content/newimage.png\" class=\"attachment-post-thumbnail\" height=\"41\" width=\"600\">" );
```

or like that `'<img src="/content/newimage.png" class="attachment-post-thumbnail" height="41" width="600">'`

```
$( "img.attachment-post-thumbnail" ).replaceWith('<img src="/content/newimage.png" class="attachment-post-thumbnail" height="41" width="600">');
```